# Why doesn't the "-j8" part of make -j8 seem to do anything in Gitlab CI?

Tags: makefile, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a `Makefile` generated by `cmake` and I wish to execute `make -j8 all` on my C++ project using Gitlab's CI runner. I use a Docker image (if that matters) and when I execute said `make -j8 all` it doesn't seem to do it in parallel, given that it takes on my pc (which isn't by any means a supercomputer) around 2 mins but 35+ mins on Gitlab.

I've tried to look up the issue but I didn't find any resource talking about `make` and Gitlab CI runner at the same time. So my question is: Why does `make` work this way? Am I missing something? How can I reduce that build time?

Comment: What platform are you running on? What's the version of make being used? Are you sure that it is not running in parallel (e.g., no `j8` in `MAKEFLAGS`) or is it just taking a long time to build? What resources are available on the runner (`nproc`, `free -m`)?

Comment: *...it doesn't seem to do it in parallel, given that it takes on my pc (which isn't by any means a supercomputer) around 2 mins but 35+ mins on Gitlab.* - Better check whether output order is indeterminate. Make without -j should have the exact same output order every time, on every platform (assuming file timestamps are the same).

Comment: The speed improvement with parallel make depends on the target platform. If your GitLab runner runs on a single-core computer without hyperthreading `make -j8` will probably have no effect at all. Do you know the hardware characteristics of your runner? If not, try maybe to add `lscpu` or an equivalent to your script.

Comment: Note also that the `cpuset_cpus`, `cpu_shares` and `cpus` docker container parameters of your GitLab/CI configuration can also restrict the CPU usage of your docker container on the runner. See the `config.toml` configuration file on your runner (e.g. `/etc/gitlab/config.toml`) and look at the `[runners.docker]` section.

Comment: It's worth noting that it may not be *possible* for `make` to 'parallelize' the build to any great extent -- if at all.  If the `makefile` has rules such as `all: a`, `a: b`, `b: c` ... `y: z` then there is only ever one target that can be updated at any given time.

Comment: `make all` is parallel, that's not the issue. I just checked the output of `lscpu` and well... it has only 1 CPU with 1 core and 1 thread per core. If I want use one with more CPU-s then I guess the shared runners won't do it, am I right?

Comment: @topkek If your shared runners have only one core and one thread per core there is absolutely no way to parallelize your build. Unless, maybe, if you have several runners and you split your build in several parts that can run in parallel on several runners.

Comment: @topkek But a simpler solution would be to find a multicore computer, install `gitlab-runner` on it and declare it as your runner. But to do this, of course, you must be root on the multicore computer (not 100% sure this is mandatory) and have the maintainer role on your GitLab project.

Answer (score 0):

As @Renaud Pacalet pointed out, the runner has only 1 core with one thread, hence running `make` in parallel is impossible.